# Route blog URL to custom route

Tags: magento2.3, router, blog, routes

I am using Magento 2 Magefan blog extension. The blog post URL is generated as below.

http://store-url/blog/post/hurry-xmas-with-family

But I want URL as below and it show the content of the above URL

http://store-url/hurry-xmas-with-family

How can this be achieved? Apart from using URL rewrite is there any other method?
I was thinking of creating a custom router but I think it will conflict with CMS router.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Router.php in your Controller, get any URL and manipulate in as you want. For your understanding, I'm attaching a code snippet of match function inside Router.php. If you find any trouble understanding it, you can ask.

````
public function match(RequestInterface $request): ?ActionInterface{
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $url_parts = explode("/", $identifier, 4);
        if (isset($url_parts[1]) == false && (strpos($identifier, $this->helperData->getStorefrontConfig('url_title')) !== false)) {
            $request->setModuleName('article');
            $request->setControllerName('index');
            $request->setActionName('index');

            return $this->actionFactory->create(Forward::class, ['request' => $request]);
        } elseif ((isset($url_parts[1]) == true) && ($url_parts[0] == $this->helperData->getStorefrontConfig('url_title'))) {
            $collection = null;
            if (isset($url_parts[2])) {
                $collection = $this->articleFactory->create()->load($url_parts[2], 'page_id');
            }
            $id = $collection->getId();

            $request->setModuleName('article');
            $request->setControllerName('index');
            $request->setActionName('view');
            $request->setParams([
                'id' => $id
            ]);
            return $this->actionFactory->create(Forward::class, ['request' => $request]);
        }
        return null;
    }```
````